# Creating a ROS subscriber within a class constructor?

Tags: ros, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,
I have a callback to some topic that is a method of a class. This works perfectly, except for the fact that I need to initialize this Subscriber within the main() function of my node. Ideally I would like to initialize it within the constructor of my class. Is there a way to do this?
In simple terms I would like to add this line to the class constructor rather than main():
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter", 1000, &Listener::callback, &listener);

Thanks
Ammar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47908/creating-a-ros-subscriber-within-a-class-constructor?/) by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 289 on 2012-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ammar,

I think you have this problem because your subscriber object doesn't live outside its scope (constructor). You need to declare it as a private object in your class

```
private:
    ros:Subscriber sub;
```

then you can initialize it in the constructor:

```
sub = n.subscribe("chatter", 1000, &Listener::callback, &listener);
```

In the main function, when you create the object, you will have a running subscriber in your object.

---

Originally posted by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) with karma: 796 on 2012-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) on 2012-11-09**:
Ahhh.... Great catch.. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just in case somebody is wondering why it doesn't compile,
In my case the accepted answer doesn't work and I have to do as follows:

```
sub = n.subscribe("chatter", 1000, &Listener::callback, this);
```

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2015-06-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3